# AABB SAT code detects collision wrongly

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection, aabb, separating-axis-theorem

I've been having trouble getting my SAT code working using AABBs, and I've been trying to find a solution but, I'm scratching my head.

For some reason, it detects collisions very wrongly, as shown by this desk check I did.
(AABBvsAABB method at bottom.)

Consider two AABB, A and B.

```
A = X: 0, Y: 0, W: 102, H: 19 

B = X = 87, Y: 6, W: 1, H: 1
```

These are colliding.

First, calculate normal

```
Normal = (0,0) - (87,6) = (-87,-6)
```

Next, we get half widths

```
aExtent = 102/2 = 51
bExtent = 1/2 = .5
```

Now lets calculate the overlap of the two.

```
 xExtent = 51 + .5 - |-87| = 51.5 - 87 =  -35.5
```

xExtent is less than zero so it says its not colliding, obviously this is wrong.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Compares bounding boxes using Seperating Axis Thereom.
   /// </summary>
   public static bool AABBvsAABB(AABB a, AABB b, ref Manifold manifold)
   {
        manifold.Normal = a.Position - b.Position;

        //Calculate half widths
        float aExtent = a.Width / 2f;
        float bExtent = b.Width / 2f;

        //Calculate the overlap.
        float xExtent = aExtent + bExtent - Math.Abs(manifold.Normal.X);

        //If the overlap is greater than 0
        if (xExtent > 0)
        {
            //Calculate half widths
            aExtent = a.Height / 2f;
            bExtent = b.Height / 2f;

            //Calculate overlap
            float yExtent = aExtent + bExtent - Math.Abs(manifold.Normal.Y);

            if (yExtent > 0)
            {
                //Variable to multiply the normal by to make the collision resolve
                Vector2 faceNormal;

                //Check to see which axis has the biggest "penetration" ;D

                //Collision is happening on Y axis
                if (xExtent > yExtent)
                {
                    faceNormal = manifold.Normal.X < 0 ? -Vector2.UnitX : Vector2.UnitX;
                    manifold.PenetrationDepth = xExtent;
                    manifold.Normal = Physics.GetNormal(a.Position, b.Position);
                    manifold.Normal.X *= faceNormal.X;
                }
                //Collision happening on X axis
                else
                {
                    faceNormal = manifold.Normal.Y < 0 ? -Vector2.UnitY : Vector2.UnitY;

                    manifold.PenetrationDepth = yExtent;
                    manifold.Normal = Physics.GetNormal(a.Position, b.Position);
                    manifold.Normal.Y *= faceNormal.Y;
                }
                manifold.AreColliding = true;
            }
        }
        return manifold.AreColliding;
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging code for you

Comment: You should try carefully printing out variables in the code to see where you went wrong. I wrote this as psuedo code (and it has some small problems). If you draw out the collision problem by hand and understand what is happening, then write your code you can usually find problems pretty easily. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing definitions for the x & y coordinates of your AABBs.

Checking for collisions using this formula with half-extents implies that your x & y coordinates represent the coordinates of the centers of the bounding boxes. In this definition, the two boxes you describe are indeed not colliding, and everything is working as expected.

If the two boxes are colliding as you say, then the coordinates must be the min-x, min-y corner. In this situation, the half-extents check is not appropriate. Instead, you'd want to use something like:

```
if(A.x < B.x)
   colliding = B.x - A.x < A.width;
else
   colliding = A.x - B.x < B.width;
```